# Data API for Amazon Aurora Serverless in spring boot

Tags: spring, orm, spring-data-jpa, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I am looking to connect **Data API for Amazon Aurora Serverless** in my **spring** application. I searched well enough but cannot find ORM support for **Data API for Amazon Aurora Serverless**. Is anybody found ORM in spring for this issue?  is there a better approach ?
note: don't specify 'rds-data-api-client-library-java'.I dont need native query solution for this. I need ORM.

Comment: Aurora seems to be MySql and PostgreSql compatible. Therefore you should be able to use JPA/Spring Data JPA.

Comment: I am asking this regarding to DATA API ?

Comment: Did you ever find anything? It seems the data api is s really good way to connect to a aws serverless database, but having to create your own sql statements is like step backwards.